# JSON reads me only objects, no arrays

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I'm using Eclipse, for an application where I have to read a JSON file from an URL.

The code I'm using is this one:

http://collegewires.com/android/2012/06/json-parsing-in-android/

Ok, the CLASS which I'm using for reading JSON files is called Parser.java:

```
package com.cw.json;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Parser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    static String json = "";
    // class constructor
    public Parser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sBuilder.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sBuilder.toString();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Parsing the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        // JSON String
        return jsonObject;

    }
}
```

I was using this code for reading a JSON file which is directly an ARRAY, but the code gives me an error.

My question is: is it possible to read an Array instead always reading an Object??
maybe using another class?

Comment: please post the error log too.

Comment: You should probably take a look at [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/). It's a much more feature-complete library for JSON serialization/deserialization.

Comment: If by "maybe using another class?" you mean another tool or library, then that part of the question is off topic for Stack Overflow: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to modify your Parser.java to this, so you gat a Array not a Object. And please buy you a JAVA Book for beginners, so you do learn how to speak JAVA

```
 public JSONArray getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
    ....
    static JSONArray jsonArray = null;
    ....
     // Parsing the string to a JSON Array
     try {
            jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
     } catch (JSONException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
     }
     return jsonArray;
  }
```